# How many development certificates can you have per Organization for the Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios

How many development certificates can you have per Organization for the Apple Developer Program?

I am asking this question because we have a team of 10 developers and still growing. So is it better idea to have a development key/certificate per a developer or maybe a single development key/certificate per an Organization which will be shared with all developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each developer should have his own certificate.